# Writing Cross-Validation in R

Tags: r, cross-validation

I'm a beginner in stats and it's my first time doing a regression model using R. I have done the basic 70/30 split for a simple lm model and I would like to code for cross-validation now, without the use of caret package. 
Here is my code:

```
cv_ss <- model2[sample(nrow(model2)),]
folds <- cut(seq(1,nrow(cv_ss)),breaks=6, labels = FALSE)
for(i in 1:6){
  testIndexes <- which(folds==i,arr.ind = FALSE)
  testData <- cv_ss[testIndexes, ]
  trainData <- cv_ss[-testIndexes, ]
  model_cv_ss <- lm(trainData$ss ~., data = trainData)
  summary(model_cv_ss)
  pred_cv_ss<-predict(model_cv_ss,testData)
  actual_cv_ss<-testData[,"ss"]

  MAPE_ss = mean(abs((pred_cv_ss - actual_cv_ss)/actual_cv_ss))
  MAPE_ss

  error_ss = abs((pred_cv_ss- actual_cv_ss)/actual_cv_ss)
  error_ss
  save_ss<- rbind(save_ss, new)
}
new <- data.frame(MAPE_ss, error_ss)
#}
#save_ss<- rbind(save_ss, new)
save_ss

avg_error_ss <- mean(MAPE_ss)
avg_error_ss
```

Here are my results:

```
 MAPE_ss   error_ss
11  0.4012435 0.01960784
10  0.4012435 0.20384160
7   0.4012435 0.70386888
151  0.4012435 0.67765551
.
.
.
```

I am very confused because:
I  only have 21 observations, but the observations can count to 151. But, in the global environment, it says only 21 observations.
Secondly, all my MAPE_ss are the same, which I think should not be the case as each fold takes in a different data, thus MAPE_ss should be different.

Do correct me if i'm wrong.

Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance! :)

Edit:
dim(model2)

```
> dim(model2)
[1] 25 13
```

dput(head(model2))

```
> dput(head(model2,20))
structure(list(ï..SST = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), SSA = c(0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SSR = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SSC = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SSF = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), SSFH = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), SSTC = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), SSH = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), SSC = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), SSW = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), QTY = c(109, 
45, 48, 49, 31, 81, 13, 48, 109, 45, 48, 49, 31, 81, 13, 48, 
36, 47, 58, 37), SS = c(53000, 47000, 5e+05, 
450000, 62000, 950000, 660000, 1060000, 530000, 480000, 520000, 
430000, 630000, 970000, 650000, 1090000, 1230374, 1695561, 981224, 
1130354), TTH. = c(60, 45, 45, 45, 45, 90, 90, 90, 
60, 45, 45, 45, 45, 95, 90, 90, 60, 90, 40, 65)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What is the output of `dim(model2)`? Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(model2)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(model2, 20))`.

Comment: When drawing a sample, rows usually keep their rowname, so the `151` may just be the rowname the row had in the original dataset before subsampling. Also, the line to create `new` is outside of your loop, therefore `save_ss` does not get updated by the line `save_ss <- rbind(save_ss, new)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, I edited with the two outputs, thanks for looking through!

Comment: @LAP, I will try editing the codes and see the result! Thanks for looking through! :)

Comment: Just put the line `new <- data.frame(MAPE_ss, error_ss)` within your `for` loop and it should work as intended.

Comment: @LAP Yes, I have different MAPE_ss now, thank you so much for your help! :)